# Ionic 2 too slow to load: White screen shows up after splashscreen

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have created apps using both Ionic 1 and 2. While I never had any problem with speed using Ionic 1, It has become too slow with Ionic 2 !! 
Is it normal ? I just tested using the tutorial startup app also, deployed it to my device and it hangs for at least 10 seconds before showing the home screen!

I did not change anything to the config.xml file. I am using the ionic 2 super template.

Comment: Is your project up to date with 3.5?

Comment: Yes. Its updated

Answer (score 1):

Use `--prod` tag while building apk.

```
ionic cordova build android --prod
```

Comment: Already did. It reduces the load time a little , But still it takes 5 to 7 seconds to load

Comment: Reinstall all your plugins and platform.